# How large should samples be to have a smooth irrational function?

Tags: tikz-pgf, gnuplot

I'm trying to draw a smooth irrational function using TikZ and gnuplot, but close to the zero of the function gaps remain.

I can *fix* this by choosing `samples=5000`, but this slows down the compiling process a lot and even then a small gap remains... It seems rather arbitrary as well.

There has to be a better way, but how?

[image: Rrrational gap]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[very thin,color=gray] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9); 
    \draw[-stealth] (-5.2,0) -- (5.2,0) node[above] {$x$}; 
    \draw[-stealth] (0,-5.2) -- (0,5.2) node[left] {$y$}; 
    \draw (1,0) node [below] {$1$};
    \draw (0,1) node [left] {$1$};
    \draw (0,0) node [below left] {$0$};
    \draw[very thick,color=blue] plot[domain=-5:5] function{1.5*(x+4)**(0.5)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that your function `1.5*(x+4)**(0.5)` is defined only for `x>=-4`, so the graph is actually plotted starting from the first point which is grater than or equal to minus four. Turns out that neither for the default sample length nor for 5000 there's no points in the sample which would be equal to -4, this accounts for the gap.

```
plot[domain=-4:5] function{1.5*(x+4)**(0.5)}
```

fixes the gap. Adding `sample=1000` pretty much fixes the plot smoothness issue which is caused by the infinite derivative (or vertical tangent line) at `x=-4`.